# Firefox extension for scaffolding web pages?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I'm looking for a Firefox extension I've recently read of that makes scaffolding web sites easy. It seemed to be a combination of Firebug and ColorZilla enabling to modify source of existing sites on the fly making it ideal to scaffold. It seemed to be rather new but unfortunaltey I couldn't find it googling.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does "scaffolding web sites" mean?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the snippet editor in safari? http://www.seifi.org/testing/whats-new-in-safari-31-web-inspector-and-sinppet-editor.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental add-on called [Firefox Add-on Kit "Matchfox"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/47147), described as:

> The best scaffold generator for
>   Firefox add-on developers. You can get
>   started your development in 5 minutes.
>
> This scaffold includes an OR mapper
>   for sqlite, a library for the
>   Preference system, and a library for
>   localized strings. Detailed reference
>   manuals are also included.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a Firefox Add-On Scaffold
There is [Firefox/Thunderbird Extension Wizard](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensionwiz/),
This is like the [Matchfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/47147) extension `harrymc` has already suggested.

Point is, all these are talking about building firefox extensions.
And, you seem to be looking for something that will scaffold web-sites.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like [Edit Page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8289).